# Autostart SSH tunnels on load (Ubuntu)

Tags: ssh, upstart

Every time I login into my computer I start a SSH connection to a remote computer for database work. How can I automate this in Ubuntu so that I don't have to type this in each time I login to my computer?

```
ssh -L 3333:dbserver:3306 user@othersite.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alias it in you `~/.bashrc`.

Add that line `alias db_connect="ssh -L 3333:dbserver:3306 user@othersite.com"`
And reload the bashrc file with `source ~/.bashrc`

And now you only have to type `db_connect` to ssh to your database server.

Comment: Hmm.. this isn't working now that I have logged out and tested it. Do you need to type anything else before "db_connect" in the prompt? It just says "command not found".

Comment: Never mind. I put the command in single quotes and it worked.

Comment: You have to either relaunch your prompt or reload your bashrc with ` source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Behold! Ye Shall Worship The Almight Aliasing! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your shell configuration to execute commands on startup. For a bash shell, simply edit `~/.bashrc` and add your connection line.